# Using regex to parse a string from text that includes a newline

Tags: java, regex

Given the following text, I'm trying to parse out the string "TestFile" after `Address:`:

```
File: TestFile
Branch


        OFFICE INFORMATION
            Address: TestFile
            City: L.A.
            District.: 43
            State: California
            Zip Code: 90210

        DISTRICT INFORMATION
            Address: TestFile2
            ....
```

I understand that lookbehinds require zero-width so quantifiers are not allowed, meaning this won't work:

```
(?<=OFFICE INFORMATION\n\s*Address:).*(?=\n)
```

I could use this

```
(?<=OFFICE INFORMATION\n            Address:).*
```

but it depends on consistent spacing, which isn't dynamic and thus not ideal.

How do I reliably parse out "TestFile" and not "TestFile2" as shown in my example above. Note that Address appears twice but I only need the first value.

Thank you

Comment: Why not use `String.split(":")` to create an array of everything whose elements are separated by `:`. You can then just iterate through that array and get whatever information you need.

Comment: I agree, @JaskaranbirSingh - @Casey, why don't you just `split()` on newlines, `trim()` whitespaces, and `split(":")`?

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh, that sounds much better. Would the results be returned in an array such that first row, first column would be Address and first row second column would be TestFile?  @anubhava, your solution seems to work but if array is more efficient I'd rather that. Can anybody provide a link to a good example of using `String.split(":")` Thanks

Comment: Added an example on how you could use split method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use a lookbehind here. Get your matched text using captured group:

```
(?:\bOFFICE INFORMATION\s+Address:\s*)(\S+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xH5lB9/3)

`captured group #1` will have value `TestFile`

**JS Code:**

```
var re = /(?:\bOFFICE INFORMATION\s+Address:\s*)(\S+)/; 
var m;
var matches = []; 
if ((m = re.exec(input)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    matches.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: your solution seems to work but if array is more efficient I'd rather that. I'll be sure to award you the checkmark if I go with your option. Any opinion on whether array is superior? Thank you

Comment: Your solution eventually proved most useful for my situation, as I had trouble implementing the other solutions. So thank you.

Comment: it seems that your RegEx demo is using php RegEx. Are you able to provide an example using Java RegEx? Currently your expression returns "OFFICE INFORMATION                    Address: TestFile" Not just TestFile

Comment: My mistake, it seems RegEx101 shows 1 Match even with Javascript, but my javascript returns "OFFICE INFORMATION Address: TestFile" Not just TestFile. Any idea why?

Comment: If you notice my answer I suggested to use captured group #1 for your matched text.

Answer (score 1):

**Working with Array:**

```
// A sample String
String questions = "File: TestFile Branch OFFICE INFORMATION Address: TestFile  City: L.A.   District.: 43       State: California     Zip Code: 90210       DISTRICT INFORMATION           Address: TestFile2";

// An array list to store split elements
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

// Split based on colon and spaces.
// Including spaces resolves problems for new lines etc
for(String x : questions.split(":|\\s"))
// Ignore blank elements, so we get a clean array
    if(!x.trim().isEmpty())
        arr.add(x);
```

This will give you an array which is:

```
[File, TestFile, Branch, OFFICE, INFORMATION, Address, TestFile, City, L.A., District., 43, State, California, Zip, Code, 90210, DISTRICT, INFORMATION, Address, TestFile2]
```

Now lets analyze... suppose you want information corresponding to `Address`, or element `Address`. This element is at position `5` in array. That means element `6` is what you want.

So you would do this:

```
String address = arr.get(6);
```

This will return you `testFile`.

Similarly for `City`, element `8` is what you want. The count starts from `0`. You can ofcourse modify my matching pattern or even create a loop and get yourself even better ways to do this task. This is just a hint.

*Here is one such example loop:*

```
// Every i+1 is the property tag, and every i+2 is the property name for 
// Skip first 6 elements because they are of no real purpose to us
for(int i = 6; i<(arr.size()/2)+6; i+=2)
    System.out.println(arr.get(i));
```

This gives following output:

```
TestFile
L.A.
43
California
Code
```

Ofcourse this loop is unrefined, refine it a little and you will get every element correctly. Even the last element. Or better yet, use `ZipCode` instead of `Zip Code` and dont use spaces in between and you will have a perfect loop with nothing much to be done in addition).

*The advantage over using direct regex:* You wont have to specify the regex for every single element. Iteration is always more handy to get things done automatically.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to explain how to use an array. The thing is, with my text file I need to determine (for instance) if "Address:" exists, then parse out its value to the right. The problem occurs with your method since there's more than one Address, and sometimes there might only be one, or three! So I can't isolate whether the currently iterated array value containing "Address" is the one I'm looking for. RegEx proves most useful, despite having to write them all.

Comment: +1 for clearly explaining the process, and you can bet this helps me on other aspects of my projects if not for this specific question. Thanks mate, truly. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
//read input from file
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("D:/tests/sample.txt"))));
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    string.append(line);
    string.append("\n");
}
//now string will contain the input as
/*File: TestFile
Branch


        OFFICE INFORMATION
            Address: TestFile
            City: L.A.
            District.: 43
            State: California
            Zip Code: 90210

        DISTRICT INFORMATION
            Address: TestFile2
            ....*/
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(OFFICE INFORMATION.*\\r?\\n.*Address:(?<officeAddress>.*)\\r?\\n)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(string.toString());
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group("officeAddress"));//prints TestFile
}
```

You can see the named group `officeAddress` in the pattern which is needed to be extracted.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, I learned a little bit from you, thank you.